# Does the Tour Example Question belong on SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

I've noticed when I looked at the **[Tour for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** the [current question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower) didn't really seems like it belonged to Stack Overflow. While I agree that the question is indeed on-topic because it deals with *Software development tools* ( as it involves swift ), to me it still doesn't really seem like a programming question that would be on SO, it appears more of a question I would expect to see on the Apple Ask Different Stack Exchange site.

Would it be a better fit for the **[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)** Stack Exchange, or should we leave it on SO as it is more popular and would get more views (and in such help more people)?

Comment: Why do you think that question is off topic on SO?  It seems appropriate to me.

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic, as I mentioned that I believe it is on-topic. It just seems like it fits Ask Different better as that deals with, and is meant for, questions about Apple software.

Comment: A question also being on topic on another site doesn't make it automatically off topic on SO, or in any way make it not belong there.  Sites are allowed to overlap to some degree, and that's fine.